# how to show store name when I add a product on cart in woocommerce(woocommerce multi store)?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I m using "OST Multiple Store" in my Woocommerce website. Now when I add a product in my cart its working fine but as it is a multi store I want to show store name as well into my cart.

**Here is my current cart:**

[image]

**How i want it:**

[image]

**Here is my woo-commerce product dashboard:**

[image]

**Now my question is how can I make this thing happen?**

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two filters
woocommerce_add_cart_item_data and woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation 
For details https://pluginrepublic.com/add-custom-cart-item-data-in-woocommerce/